# Incorrect number of rows updated upon using Rand(Checksum(Newid()))

Tags: sql-server-2008, random

I have a SP which returns the count, i need to use this count and update random rows(count number of rows) in some other table , the count returned will always be lesser or equal than the number of rows available, so the random rows should always be available

below is the method i am using

i currently have 7 rows for the where clause and the count returned is also 7, but upon different tries, the below logic marks 1 for 5 or 6 rows and never 7, is it some drawback with using rand function?

is there any alternative to this?

```
                  EXEC @Randcount=dbo.[Usp_getcount] 

                        UPDATE [mytable] 
                        SET    [output] = 1 
                        WHERE  [id] IN 
                               (SELECT TOP (@Randcount) 
                               [id]  FROM   [dbo].[mytable] 
                                WHERE 
                               [empid] = @empid  AND [setId] = @setID
                               ORDER  BY Rand(Checksum(Newid())))
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a full runnable example demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no *guarantee* on how many times that subquery will be evaluated. If it was evaluated just once for the entire query, you'd expect to get exactly 7 rows updated. But if it's evaluated once per outer row, then it's effectively a coin toss for every row.

Simplest way that should work is to split this into two separate queries:

```
EXEC @Randcount=dbo.[Usp_getcount] 

declare @IDs table (ID int not null)

insert into @IDs(ID)
SELECT TOP (@Randcount) 
  [id]  FROM   [dbo].[mytable] 
   WHERE 
 [empid] = @empid  AND [setId] = @setID
ORDER  BY Rand(Checksum(Newid()))

UPDATE [mytable] 
 SET    [output] = 1 
WHERE  [id] IN 
 (SELECT ID from @IDs)
```

Comment: @damien_the_unbeliever- yes it gets called every once per outer row

Comment: @G-- it's not guaranteed either way. A smart optimizer *may* choose to spool the results of the subquery and so it would only have evaluated it once. In this specific instance, it appears to not be doing so.

Comment: @damien_the_unbeliever- so is there anything i could do to ensure it marks exact number of rows?, because this code gets executed inside a while loop,

Comment: @G-- - as I've said in my answer - split the query into two parts, so that we now know that the original subquery is run exactly once and then the *result* of that evaluation is used in the `IN()` clause.